# Meaning of Baseline Before Sum to Zero

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

I am trying to specify a Bayesian hierarchical split-plot model in JAGS. I have been following *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis* by John K. Kruschke, however the model I am attempting is not included in his book. It is a split-plot longitudinal design with one three-level, between-Subjects categorical predictor `XGroup` and one continuous repeated measures predictor `XTime`, measured at four time points. I have attempted the equivalent of a random-slopes hierarchical regression model. The model works without sum-to-zero constraints placed on the variables, however I would like to respect this requirement as it seems to be important. While I can follow it for Kruschke's examples in the book, when it comes to doing it myself I am lost. As you can see below I have tried to impose this constraint on the between-subjects intercepts. But I don't know whether this is correct and how much further I need to go.

My model string is included below. I have taken Krsuchke's approach of specifying the parameters in the link function as `a` and then changing this to `b` for the sum to zero parameters. Any advice about how much further I need to go and how to go about it would be most welcome.

```
"model {

  # start with the likelihood function. This is the equivalent of a random slopes hierarchical regression, with a between-Ss predictor, a within-Ss predictor, and a subject level predictor (which is the random intercept), as well as the interaction between between- and within-Ss predictor, and the interaction between the within-Ss and subject-level predictor (the random slope).
  for (r in 1:nTotal) {
    y[r] ~ dt(mu[r], 1/ySigma^2, nu)
    mu[r] <- a0 + aB[XGroup[r]] + aW*XTime[r] + aS[XSubject[r]] + aBxW[XGroup[r]]*XTime[r] + aSxW[XSubject[r]]*XTime[r]
  }


  # now it's just a matter of specifying the priors for each parameter in the model

  # prior on ySigma
  ySigma ~ dunif(sdY/100, sdY*10)

  # prior on nu
  nu ~ dexp(1/30.0)

  # prior on the baseline
  a0 ~ dnorm(mY, 1/(sdY*5)^2)

  # prior on the between-groups
  for (gIdx in 1:nXGroupLevels) {
    aB[gIdx] ~ dnorm(0, 1/sigmaB^2)
  }

  # prior on deflection variance parameters
  sigmaB ~ dgamma(aGammaShapeRate[1], aGammaShapeRate[2])

  # prior on within-subjects
  aW ~ dnorm(0, 1/sigmaW^2)

  # prior on variance of within-Ss
  sigmaW ~ dgamma(aGammaShapeRate[1], aGammaShapeRate[2])

  # prior on subject-level
  for (sIdx in 1:nXSubjectLevels) {
    aS[sIdx] ~ dnorm(0, 1/sigmaS^2)
  }

  # prior on variance of subject intercepts
  sigmaS ~ dgamma(aGammaShapeRate[1], aGammaShapeRate[2])

  # prior on b x w interaction
  for (gIdx in 1:nXGroupLevels) {
    aBxW[gIdx] ~ dnorm(0, 1/BxWSigma^2)
  }

  # prior on between-group variance of slope deflections
  BxWSigma ~ dgamma(aGammaShapeRate[1], aGammaShapeRate[2])

  # prior on s x w interaction
  for (sIdx in 1:nXSubjectLevels) {
    aSxW[sIdx] ~ dnorm(0, 1/SxWSigma^2)
  }

  # prior on variance of between-subject variance of slope deflections
  SxWSigma ~ dgamma(aGammaShapeRate[1], aGammaShapeRate[2])

  # now we need to transform to sum-to-zero contrasts 

  # first the raw predicted group means for each level m[gIdx] are calculated as the estimated baseline plus the group mean
  for ( gIdx in 1:nXGroupLevels ) { m[gIdx] <- a0 + aB[gIdx] }

  # for the grand mean b0
  b0 <- mean(m[1:nXGroupLevels])

  # now we arrive at the sum-to-zero deflection for each group by subtracting the baseline from each group mean (calculated via the procedure 2 #'s back)
  for (gIdx in 1:nXGroupLevels) { bB[gIdx] <- m[gIdx] - b0 }

}
"
```

The model compiles and runs, and `bB1 + bB2 + bB3` sum to zero.

`a0`, the grand mean prior to the sum-to-zero procedure is 31.57 and `b0`, the grand mean *after* the sum-to-zero procedure, is 31.68, an increase of 0.1095. `bB1-aB1`, `bB2-aB2`, and `bB3-aB3` all equal -0.1095. Thus the estimated intercept for group 1 will be exactly the same if you calculate it as `a0 + aB1` or `b0 + bB1` (and the same for intercept estimates for groups 2 and 3). Furthermore the estimated *difference* between group intercepts will be exactly the same before the sum-to-zero as after. All that changes is the 'grand intercept' `a0` (and, I presume, its meaning).

So my questions are:

(1) 'what is `a0`?' What does it represent? `b0` is obviously the average of the group intercepts. But what is `a0`?

(2) What other parameters in my model should I be performing the sum-to-zero procedure for? I suspect it will be necessary for the group x time parameter `aBxW`? If so, do I do this in the same manner as I have for the intercept, except with reference to the within-subjects parameter `aW` instead of the intercept `a0`?

Comment: Does this model compile, run, and give you contrasts that sum to zero?

Comment: Yes @user43849 it compiles, runs, and `bB1 + bB2 + bB3 = 0`. You'd think I would have thought to check this given the procedure is called 'sum-to-zero' but once again I have missed something obvious. I had some questions after calculating differences between pre-sum-to-zero estimates  (with `a` prefixes) and post-sum-to-zero estimates  (with `b` prefixes). My questions were too long to fit in a comment so I have added them to the end of the original post.